# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”) Error on a lot of different websites

Tags: firefox, security, browser, http, javascript

Since a couple of days ago, i cannot reach a lot of Well-Known Websites like : **Github.com,linkedIn,...** .

I am using Firefox 81.0.1.

when i open console, in found this error line:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)
```

and when i follow **The Source** in the console it came from a couple of extensions like : ReactDevTools,ReduxTools,Jetpack, Keepassxc,...

I want to Know What happened because The Browser Would browse every sites 2 days ago, but not yesterday and today???

[image: I Couldnt Reach Github.com]

I am Writing this post with Another Browser

Comment: Disable all the extensions. If that fixes it add them back one by one till you know which one is broken ...

Comment: Thanks David, But after disabling all of the extensions,  errors in console for github vanished, and there are just warnings, but linked in has got some errors, one of them is CSP (Content Security Policy). But **None of the Sites wont Load**, and the problem persists. its so weird.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is your case, but I was having exactly the same problem and I just figured out that the problem was an Add-On that I use (YesScript2) for blocking javascript and I accidentally had activated it for my page.

So if you have any add-on that blocks javascript, verify if they are not active for that page you are having problems with.

Good luck